# How could i get event type in vue when watch listener triggered?

Tags: vue.js, events, parameters, watch

I have created a wacther and when `<Input v-model="computedData" />` changes the data, I can get the old and new values. Data can also be changed via `XMLHttpRequest`. I need to know who changed the data. I can't get `event` as parameter via `watcher` when data changes. Because there is no argument to get to `event` on whatcher. I know, I can access the event directly using `event`. But I also know it's `deprecated`. So I'm researching how the event type can be accessed as `InputEvent` nor `XMLHttpRequest`.

```js
  @Options({
    name: 'dx-table',
    watch: {
      computedData: {
        handler(newData: any, oldData: any) {
          console.log(event); // is there any way to access `event` without using `event` directly
        },
        deep: true,
        immediate: true,
      },
    },
  })
  export default class DxTable extends Vue.with(Props) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the event or cause of the data change in a watcher. A watcher is simply a function that executes whenever some reactive property changes and all you are given is the old value and the new value.

Based on the information given, there's two ways the data can be changed:

1. **input** event: Register a listener for the input event on the component, like `@input="handleInput"`. The event object is passed to the function.
2. **XMLHttpRequest**: Wherever you are changing the property in code, just call a method to handle that specific mutation.

I don't know specifics about your code, but this might be a situation where instead of mutating the data freely throughout your code, use one or more "setter" methods to do this so that you know exactly where and how the data is being mutated. Using a watcher gives you *no information* about where or how the data changed, and if you're mutating the data in many random places in your codebase then you're going to have a difficult time trying to trace through your code to find the cause of the mutation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `<dx-table :data="sampleData" />` In this example, I give `sampleData` to component. The value of "sampleData" changes using "input" or "XMLHttpRequest". In the table component's watcher, I want to know `event` type of change causes when data changed. But as you mentioned, it is not possible with watcher. So, I will use default `event` parameter for get event type information.